# Message: Trying to get property of non-object in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I want to display detail data from each table (*as foreign key*), but not all show.

***I have this code in my Model page:**

```
class m_masterinventory extends CI_Model{
public function detail_datasset($id = NULL) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('inv_inventory', array('id' => $id))->result();
        return $query;
}
```

***And this my view page**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <td><?= $asset->initial; ?><?= date('yd', $asset->device); ?>

</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <td><?= $asset->name; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Organization</th>
        <td><?= $asset->organization_id; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <td><?= $asset->brand; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <td><?= $asset->category; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <td><?= $asset->model; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
        <td><?= $asset->sn; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <td><?= $asset->status; ?></td>
      </tr>
```

***And this my controller page**

```
public function detail_asset($id){
    $this->load->model('m_masterinventory');

    $asset = $this->m_masterinventory->detail_datasset($id);
    $data['asset'] = $asset;

    $this->load->view('inv/detail-master-asset', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_array()` instead of `result();` as you are fetching single row.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('inv_inventory', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
```

and in your view use array  `$asset['category']`; instead of `$asset->category;`

Comment: the result is looping, and data from other tables are numbers. I want to combine data from another table in the form of characters

Answer (score 0):

```
$asset = $this->m_masterinventory->detail_datasset($id);
```

`$asset` is an array, not a single value.
so you need to write like this in your view if this is a one-row result.

`<td><?= $asset[0]['name']; ?></td>`

and this is good if the result is one row and you don't want to use an array, then you need to use `row_array()` in your model.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('inv_inventory', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
```

In this time you can write like this in your view.

`<td><?= $asset['name']; ?></td>`

Comment: the result is looping, and data from other tables are numbers. I want to combine data from another table in the form of characters (as joined table). Can help?

Comment: Provide other table data fields